# Clone proxy object into current AppDomain

Tags: c#

For my project I need to access resources from other .Net assembly, but I don't want to keep them loaded, as I may load different version of the same assembly.

So for doing that I create another AppDomain with which I use CreateInstanceAndUnwrap to create a custom class that descend from MarshalByRefObject. In that class I load the assembly and it has a function to return resource objects (string,bitmap,etc).

Now the problem is that I cannot keep the reference to theses object after the temporary AppDomain is Unloaded (except for value-type objects like structs), an AppDomainUnloadedException is thrown.

So is it possible to copy into the current AppDomain an object obtained from another AppDomain, knowing that theses object will all probably be Serializable or implement ISerializable?

It may be important to note that Bitmap inherits from MarshalByRefObject, implements ISerializable and has the Serializable attribute. Here is a small snippet to demonstrate the issue.

```
class ImageGrabber : MarshalByRefObject 
{
     public Image GetImage() { return new Bitmap(16,16); }
}

//testing
var tmpDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("test");
var proxy = (ImageGrabber)tmpDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
     typeof(ImageGrabber).Assembly.FullName, 
     typeof(ImageGrabber).FullName);
Bitmap myImage = proxy.GetImage();
AppDomain.Unload(tmpDomain);
pictureBox.Image = myImage;//throws AppDomainUnloadedException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like Bitmaps don't like to be serialized... Many of its properties are of types not marked as serializable, even the Save method don't work as it must use properties that the proxy object cannot serialize. So I have no choice but to convert the image into a stream (or byte array would work too) in the code running in the temporary AppDomain.

Then again, that stream is still attached to the AppDomain but thankfully the stream type serialize without a hitch so I can just copy it into a MemoryStream.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific context, you may use [System.Drawing.ImageConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imageconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
var myImage = proxy.GetImage();

var converter = new ImageConverter();
var data = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(myImage, typeof(byte[]);

AppDomain.Unload(tmpDomain);
pictureBox.Image = (Bitmap)converter.ConvertFrom(data);
```

Note: in your question's code, I don't think this compiles, btw:

```
Bitmap myImage = proxy.GetImage();
```

'HTH,